# Write To Nested Dictionary (Kotlin)

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

I have declared a dictionary in Swift as such: `private val nestedDictionary = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>>()`

What I am trying to do now is to write to the nested dictionary. Below is the code that I am using.
`nestedDictionary["First Layer"]["Second Layer"] = mutableListOf("Failing to Write")`

What I am trying to do is to create a dictionary key for ["First Layer"], and then map values into it. How might I do that?

Edit: The code that I have currently and is receiving this error: 'the expression cannot be a selector.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Simulant's answer will overwrite the existing value for `"First Layer"`, if there is one. If that's not what you want, use [`getOrPut`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html):

```
nestedDictionary.getOrPut("First Layer", { mutableMapOf() })["Second Layer"] = 
    mutableListOf("Failing to Write")
```

Answer (score 1):

`nestedDictionary["First Layer"]` can return a not `null` value. So you cannot chain `nestedDictionary["First Layer"]["Second Layer"]` as this implies that the value stored at `nestedDictionary["First Layer"]` exists.

You can use the [not null assertion operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) to force your code execution. However you will get a `KoltinNullPointerException` if the value at `nestedDictionary["First Layer"]` was not initialized before.

```
val nestedDictionary = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, List<String>>>()
nestedDictionary["First Layer"]!!["Second Layer"] = mutableListOf("possible to write")
```

Result

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at main(Main.kt:4)
```

this works because the map in between is initialized

```
val nestedDictionary = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, List<String>>>()
nestedDictionary["First Layer"] = HashMap()
nestedDictionary["First Layer"]!!["Second Layer"] = mutableListOf("possible to insert")
```

A cleaner solution would be

```
val nestedDictionary = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>>()
nestedDictionary["First Layer"] = mutableMapOf("Second Layer" to mutableListOf("inserted"))
```

Comment: Upvoted: I love the clean solution of `nestedDictionary["First Layer"]!!["Second Layer"]`.

Comment: How would I append an item to the mutableMapOf["Second Layer"]/create it if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty solution:

```
nestedDictionary["First Layer"]?.put("Second Layer", mutableListOf("Failing to Write"))
// Map.get() is nullable
```

or

```
nestedDictionary["First Layer"] = mutableMapOf("Second Layer" to mutableListOf("Failing to Write"))
```

or

```
nestedDictionary["First Layer"]!! += "Second Layer" to mutableListOf("Failing to Write")
// throw exception if no "First Layer" in nestedDictionary.
```